# Atbash Cipher in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and C# and i'm trying to make Atbash Cipher in C#.
So I'm stuck at this problem: the cipher ran good, but they don't put spacing, or special characters (that not need to encode) in the result. I tried to make it but it got repeated.

So is there a way to let it skip the non-alphabet characters and put it on result ?

Here is my code

```
using System;

namespace AtbashCipher
{
class Program
    {
    static void Main()
        {

        Console.WriteLine("Atbash cipher v1.0");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Enter messages: ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();


        string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string AlphabetUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string result = "";
        Boolean SpecialChar = false;

        foreach (char c in userInput)               
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Alphabet.Length; i++)
            {
                if (c == Alphabet[i])                           
                {
                    result += Alphabet[Alphabet.Length - 1 - i];

                }
                if (c == AlphabetUpper[i])                      
                {
                    result += AlphabetUpper[AlphabetUpper.Length - 1 - i];

                }
            }

        }

        //Print result for user
        Console.WriteLine("Encoded messages: " + result);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it step by step aka. debug it? You'll find that you never reach a line that is `result += c;`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task recently and here is my approach:

```
private string GetAtbash(string s)
{
    var charArray = s.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = charArray[i];

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            charArray[i] = (char) (96 + (123 - c));
        }

        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            charArray[i] = (char) (64 + (91 - c));
        }
    }

    return new String(charArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append the character if it's not between `a-z` or `A-Z`. You can check if `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` and simply append `c` to `result` if that's not the case.

Comment: Can you explain for me why `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` work, like how C# know how to compare between A-Z without writing down alphabet?

Comment: Characters are just stored as 2 byte big numbers. Have a look at the  [Unicode table](http://unicode-table.com/en/) to understand why you can simply compare them or do mathematical operations with them